# Error in my backend when I'm trying to send an array of ObjectID from a post router from my frontend (React-Native/Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

It's only been a few months that I've begun coding. I'm currently working on a project to create an application for shopping on React-Native with Mongoose as my database.
I'm trying to post in my database my customer's order but my terminal crash because it doesn't recognize my array of articles.

**My order model is :**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

var orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  OrderNumber: String,

 totalOrder: Number,

  shippingCost: Number,

  date_insert: Date,

  date_shipment: Date,

  articles: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "articles" }],

});

var OrderModel = mongoose.model("orders", orderSchema);

module.exports = OrderModel;
```

**my index.js:**

```
router.post("/orders", async function (req, res, next) {

var result = false;

var response = false;

var orderNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(1000000) + 1);

var shippingCost = 5;

var user = await UserModel.findOne({ token: req.body.token });

  if (user != null) {

    var newOrder = new OrderModel({

      OrderNumber: orderNumber,

      totalOrder: req.body.totalOrder,

      shippingCost: shippingCost,

      date_insert: req.body.date_insert,

      date_shipment: req.body.date_shipment,

      articles: req.body.articles,

      locker: req.body.locker,
    });

    var orderSave = await newOrder.save();

    if (orderSave) {
      result = true;
    }
  
    if (result) {
      user.orders.push(orderSave._id);
      response = true;
      await user.save();
      res.json({ user, response });
    } else {
      res.json(err.message);
    }
  } else {

    res.json("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

**In my frontend**

My article basket is store in a reducer saveBasket

```
var tab = [];

  var idList = props.saveBasket.map((article, i) => {

    tab = [...tab, article._id];
  });

var handleSubmitOrder = async () => {
  
    const data = await fetch("https://heroku.project.com/orders", {

      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: `totalOrder=${props.saveValidateCart}&date_insert=${currentDate}&date_shipment=${deliveryDate}&articles=${tab}&locker=${props.saveIdLocker._id}&token=${props.saveToken}`,
    });
    const body = await data.json();
    
  };
```

**The error show on my terminal is :**

```
/Users/Documents/BackEnde/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4650
  const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "621cb042067e1819e87f7ee8,621cb2b4067e1819e87f7eef" (type string) at path "_id" for model "articles"
    at model.Query.exec

(/Users/Documents/BackEnd/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4650:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then 

(/Users/Documents//BackEnd/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4749:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"621cb042067e1819e87f7ee8,621cb2b4067e1819e87f7eef"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '621cb042067e1819e87f7ee8,621cb2b4067e1819e87f7eef',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
      at new BSONTypeError (/Users/Documents/fraiche/BackEnd/node_modules/bson/lib/error.js:41:28)
      at new ObjectId 

(/Users/Documents/BackEnd/node_modules/bson/lib/objectid.js:65:23)
      at castObjectId 
(/Users/Documents/BackEnd/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast/objectid.js:24:12)
      at ObjectId.cast 

(/Users/Documents/BackEnd/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:247:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters 

(/Users/Documents/BackEnd/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1179:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery 

(/Users//Documents/BackEnd/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1613:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery 

(/Users/Documents/BackEnd/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1603:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper 

(/Users//Documents/BackEnd/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1580:20)
      at cast (/Users//Documents/BackEnd/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:344:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast 

(/Users/Documents/BackEnd/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:5085:12),
  valueType: 'string'

I don't understand because when I console.log tab in my front end, an array with my articles id is shown but when send on my backend it ends up being a string?!
```

Can someone help me understand what is wrong?
Thank you and sorry for any grammatical mistake, English isn't my native language

Answer (score 1):

You are sending 2 IDs to the server as a `String`, they need to be properly parsed. If IDs are articles try doing this in the backend, where you're constructing your order

```js
    var newOrder = new OrderModel({
      OrderNumber: orderNumber,
      totalOrder: req.body.totalOrder,
      shippingCost: shippingCost,
      date_insert: req.body.date_insert,
      date_shipment: req.body.date_shipment,
      articles: req.body.articles.split(",").map(article => ObjectId(article)),
      locker: req.body.locker,
    });
```

Comment: No problem, If it helped you mark as an answer so it can help others

Answer (score 0):

This is your issue here:

```
body: `totalOrder=${props.saveValidateCart}&date_insert=${currentDate}&date_shipment=${deliveryDate}&articles=${tab}&locker=${props.saveIdLocker._id}&token=${props.saveToken}`,
```

Your `node` app is looking for a JSON object in the post request and you're passing in a single `string` of url parameters .

Try this. I don't know how your `props` is structured but this should get you close.

```
const url = "https://heroku.project.com/orders";

const body = {
   totalOrder: props.saveValidateCart,
   date_insert: currentDate,
   date_shipment: deliveryDate,
   articles: tab,
   locker: props.saveIdLocker._id,
   token: props.saveToken
};

const requestOptions = {
   method: "POST",
   headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
   body: JSON.stringify(body)
};

const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);

const data = await response.json();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering I tried with Semperlabs 's answer and it worked,